# Redis server deleted after rebooting the machine

Tags: redis

I am working with redis 3.0.7 on Ubuntu. Everytime im doing reboot and then starting redis server using "nohup redis-server &" all the keys-values content is deleted.

I checked the snapshotting and in redis.conf and i have the default configuration of:

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

The machine was up for a long time (months) before the first reboot.

Any idea why this could be happenning?

Answer (score 0):

Ok apperantly i have to start the server from where the dump file actually is. found it, works now.